# sorting a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix that contains ( 6 rows, 2 columns) as shown in the attached image.

[image]

I'd like to have a new matrix (in MATLAB) that contains the second columns arranged in ascending order, but would like to keep their corresponding values in the row.
for example: the output matrix looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
mat = randi(30, [6 2]);  % creating the matrix
[mat(:,2),ind] = sort(mat(:,2));
mat(:,1) = mat(ind,1);
```

If you have access to the `sortrows` function, it is simpler:

```
mat = sortrows(mat,2);
```